# How to achieve following output in Mongo Aggregation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For the below dataset I want to receive the documents in such a way that if the user has the role of `manager` and it is `active` then I want to ignore all the other records of that user with the role `user` but if `manager` with `active` false then I want all the records with role `user` it doesn't matter if it is active or not
2.If the record with role `manager` doesn't exist I want all the role `user` records for that user and vice versa

```
    [
      0:{
        role:"manager",
        user:"john",
        active:true
      },
      1:{
        role:"user",
        region:"us",
        user:"john",
        active:false
      },
      2:{
         role:"user",
        region:"czk",
        user:"john",
        active:false
      },
      3:{
        role:"user",
        region:"czk",
        user:"jane",
        active:false
      },
      4:{
        role:"user",
        region:"us",
        user:"jane",
        active:true
      },
      5:{
        role:"manager",
        user:"jane",
        active:false
      },
    ]
```

So in Above case index `0 and 3,4` will be fetched from database
So far for achieving this output i'd tried this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      $or:[
           { $and: [{ role: manager }, { active: true }]},
           { $and: [{ role: user }, { active: true }] }
      ]
    }
  }   
])
```

but it does not give the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not as straightforward. You will have to first group the documents by `username`, and then filter out the grouped documents array, according to your criteria. This is one way of doing it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "filterStatus": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$docs",
          "initialValue": {
            managerWithActiveTrue: false,
            managerWithActiveFalse: false,
            managerIsPresent: false,
            userIsPresent: false
          },
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$value",
              {
                managerWithActiveTrue: {
                  "$or": [
                    {
                      "$and": [
                        {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$this.role",
                            "manager"
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$this.active"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.managerWithActiveTrue"
                  ]
                },
                managerWithActiveFalse: {
                  "$or": [
                    {
                      "$and": [
                        {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$this.role",
                            "manager"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $not: "$$this.active"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.managerWithActiveFalse"
                  ]
                },
                managerIsPresent: {
                  "$or": [
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$this.role",
                        "manager"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.managerIsPresent"
                  ]
                },
                userIsPresent: {
                  "$or": [
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$this.role",
                        "user"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.userIsPresent"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "docs": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$or": [
                  "$filterStatus.managerWithActiveTrue",
                  {
                    $not: "$filterStatus.userIsPresent"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$docs",
                  "as": "item",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$item.role",
                      "manager"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$or": [
                  "$filterStatus.managerWithActiveFalse",
                  {
                    $not: "$filterStatus.managerIsPresent"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$docs",
                  "as": "item",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$item.role",
                      "user"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          default: "$docs"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

In this query, we first group the documents by username, then calculate a new field named `filterStatus`, in which store of the four given conditions which ones apply to the user. Finally, we filter the array using the `filterStatus` field in `$switch`, and then we unwind the array, and bring the `docs` to the root again, using `$replaceRoot`.

This is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NSu0JuPKknM).

Comment: Cool, I have removed some unnecessary computations from the query. Please take a look here https://mongoplayground.net/p/p8cg9YFFgum